# Getting a Commit returned after a commit with no changes

Tags: javers

If I commit the same entity twice, the first time with changes and the second time without any changes, I receive a Commit with a CommitId both times. The first one holds the changes, the second has a empty changes list.

Is this behaviour intentional? I would expect to not get a CommitId for the second commit as there is no change and also no commit in the database. I got around the issue by checking if the changes list is not empty.

My Repository

```
public class CustomerRepository {

    private final Javers javers;

    CustomerRepository(Javers javers) {
        this.javers = javers;
    }

    public Optional<CommitId> save(Customer customer, Metadata metadata) {
        try {
            var author = Optional.ofNullable(metadata.author())
                    .orElse("unknown");

            Commit commit = javers.commit(author, customer); //<-- this returns a Commit with a CommitId

            return Optional.of(commit.getId());
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.warn("Couldn't commit customer", exception);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public ChangesByCommit getCommitForCustomer(CustomerId customerId, CommitId commitId) {
        var query = QueryBuilder
                .byInstanceId(customerId.getValue(), Customer.class)
                .withCommitId(commitId)
                .withChildValueObjects()
                .build();
        return javers.findChanges(query).groupByCommit().stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new CommitNotFoundException(customerId, commitId));
    }
}
```

and my test case would be this

```
    @Test
    void emptyCommit() {
        var customer = new Customer(new CustomerId("id"));
        var metadata = new Metadata("author");
        Optional<CommitId> initialCommit = repository.save(customer, metadata);

        assertThat(initialerCommit).isPresent();

        customer.addDeliveryAddressToAddressBookList(new DeliveryAddress("name", "surname", "street", "city"));

        Optional<CommitId> commitWithChanges = repository.save(customer, metadata);
        Optional<CommitId> commitWithoutChanges = repository.save(customer, metadata);

        assertThat(commitWithChanges).isPresent();
        assertThat(commitWithoutChanges).isPresent();

        ChangesByCommit initialChanges = repository.getCommitForCustomer(new CustomerId(customer.getId()), initialCommit.get());
        ChangesByCommit addedAddressBookChanges = repository.getCommitForCustomer(new CustomerId(customer.getId()), commitWithChanges.get());
        assertThrows(CommitNotFoundException.class, () ->  repository.getCommitForCustomer(new CustomerId(customer.getId()), commitWithoutChanges.get()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Javers works, you can have empty commit (without snapshots), but you can't have *no commit*. This design is expressed in Javers API, when you call `javers.commit()` you get a `Commit` object and not `Optional<Commit>`.

Comment: okay, and can you explain the reasoning behind having a CommitId generated for the empty commit? For me it seems counterintuitive to get a CommitId with which I can build a query, but get nothing returned when querying for that CommitId.